# Как создать глубокую ссылку на aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Я создаю бота модератора, и чтобы подключить его к группе пользователя, я использую deep linking (глубокую ссылку)

Моя глубокая ссылка отвечает за автоматический выбор прав админа, но как при этом не потерять авто */start*.

**Мне нужно чтобы когда пользователь добавил бота он автоматически написал в группу */start.***

> Простите что нет примера кода.